# How to implement imports within an xtext grammar

Tags: java, eclipse, import, dsl, xtext

I want to be able to create libraries with blocks in them, import the library in a separate file and then use the blocks from the library in a blockUse statement.

I have created the following grammar:

```
grammar org.xtext.example.mydsl.MyDsl with org.eclipse.xtext.common.Terminals

generate myDsl "http://www.xtext.org/example/mydsl/MyDsl"

Program:
    (imports+=Import)*
    (libraries+=Library)*
    (customBlocks+= Block)*
    (blockUses+= BlockUse)*
;

Import:
    'import' importedNamespace=QualifiedNameWithWildcard
;

QualifiedNameWithWildcard:
    QualifiedName '.*'?
;

QualifiedName:
    ID ('.' ID)*
;

Library:
    'Library' name=QualifiedName
        (blocks+=Block)+
    'EndLibrary'
;

Block:
    'block' name=ID
;

BlockUse:
    'show' block=[Block|QualifiedName]
;
```

My end goal is that I could create two files, one with a library, and one using blocks from that library like this:

File 1:

```
Library lib1
    block block1
    block block2
EndLibrary
```

File 2:

```
import lib1.*
show block1
```

I believe the bulk of my confusion comes from the meaning behind `importedNamespace` and using `cross references`

These are some of the examples I have already tried to follow:

http://www.eclipse.org/Xtext/documentation/102_domainmodelwalkthrough.html#add-imports
http://blog2.vorburger.ch/2013/05/xtext-dsl-with-epackage-namespace.html
https://blogs.itemis.com/en/in-five-minutes-to-transitive-imports-within-a-dsl-with-xtext

Answer (score 1):

imported namespaces shall not be references. thus you either have to change this

```
Import:
     'import' importedNamespace=QualifiedNameWithWildcard
;
```

or you need to adapt the calculation of the namespace resolvers e.g. in `org.eclipse.xtext.scoping.impl.ImportedNamespaceAwareLocalScopeProvider.getImportedNamespace(EObject)` and use the nodemodel to retrieve the import text there.

Make sure the project has Xtext Builder and Xtext Nature and Build Automatically is enabled and you did a clean build.

[image]

Comment: Okay, I made that change but the import is still not getting resolved. any other ideas?

Comment: for me it works fine. are you sure you have build automatically on?

Comment: Yes, I have build automatically on, I run the workflow, generate artifacts and then run the mydsl project as an eclipse application. I can use blocks created in a library in the same file, but I can't import those blocks into another file

Comment: Or is there something else I need to look at besides my grammar?

Comment: no can you please update the grammar to the state you have it now. and make sure you dont forget to regenerate and restart the runtime eclipse

Comment: Okay, I updated it. I've regenerated and restarted, when I create the files I mentioned in my question I get an error saying "Couldn't resolve reference to Block 'block1'"

Comment: Can you please share the complete dsl and sample project. Are you sure the sample project is an xtext project ( See configure context menu)

Comment: Hm, unfortunately being behind corporate proxy I cant use a public file share, could we move this to chat and i'll post everything on there? Oh and it is an xtext project

Comment: Wow, so I created a new project and copied my grammar into it and it works. I don't know what was wrong with my original project. As a follow up question if you don't mind. When I do that import lib1.* it also makes available any custom blocks i have defined outside of the library. Is there a way to make it only pull blocks within the library into scope?

Comment: Does it work if you use qualified names if not there is something wrong with your sample project
Can you share a screenshot of package explorer and the contents of .project file

Comment: added an example to my answer

Comment: what do you mean my custom blocks outside of the libary?

Comment: so in my grammar I have (libraries+=Library)* (customBlocks+=Block)*. So I could do this in my one file. `Library lib1 block block1 EndLibrary block customBlock` But in another file i should not be able to do `import lib1.* show customBlock`

Comment: then you can to customize `IDefaultResourceDescriptionStrategy` by subclassing `DefaultResourceDescriptionStrategy` and not indexing custom blocks.

Comment: Ah and that's where that comes into play, Thank you very much. Sorry that my main question was just a runaround because of a bug in the project configuration somewhere.